# Eclipse Import "Finish" error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a folder on my Desktop for an APK I would like to open using Eclipse however after going through the procedures of choosing the files I am greeted by the "Finish" button not wanting to let me click it.

The destination is New > Project > Android > Android Project from Existing Code and it does not allowed me to click the Finish button.

Comment: it means no project file is there

Comment: I have a .project and .classfile in the destination however.

Comment: Use Android Studio.

Comment: I have it installed + Android SDK Manager, where from there?

Comment: Just to hack around, create a new android project in Eclipse, copy .classfile and .project file and replace according to your actual project and try to import. On a side node check if java nature and android nature is available in those file.